# http get request error on angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

Im trying to use the http method get request and i have some issues to subscribe the respond.
here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileService{
http: any;
url: String;
date: Date;

constructor(http:Http){
this.http = http;
this.date = new Date();
//this.baseurl = 'www.google.com';
}

get_heb_date():String{
var year = this.date.getFullYear();
var month = this.date.getMonth();
var day = this.date.getDay();
//var after_sunset = 1;
//var convert_from_gregorian_to_hebrew = 1;
return this.http.get('http://www.hebcal.com/converter/?fg=json&gy='+year+'&gm='+month+'&gd='+day+'&g2h=1')
.map(res => res.json());
 }}
```

here is my component where im trying to get the "GET" request.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { JewristService } from '../../app/services/jewrist.service';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProfileService } from '../../app/services/profile.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
selector: 'page-profile',
templateUrl: 'profile.html',
providers: [ProfileService]
})
export class ProfilePage {
username: String;
loggedin: Boolean;
date: String;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private _httpservice: ProfileService) {
this.username = 'null';
}
ngOnInit(){
console.log('Profile component is running..');
this._httpservice.get_heb_date().subscribe(
data => this.date = JSON.stringify(data)
 ); }}
```

my IDE is ATOM on windows, and thats the problem it specify:
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'String'.

Answer (score 0):

it should be Observable.

```
get_heb_date():Observable<string> // http return Observable<the_result_type>
```

Comment: Cannot find name Observable

Comment: i added import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx

Comment: and another error received:
Cannot find module angular2/router

Comment: Somewhere in ur component u use routing? Then u need to include router in your app module

Comment: i dont use any routes.

Comment: ive created a template called tabs in ionic2 and i changed the 2 existed tabs and tried to use the GET method.  i dont know whats wrong. do you want me to show you the content of any specific files?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was inside the main.ts

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

the name of the module was not set up.
Now it works.
Thanks.